# What is a difference between security token and security ticket?

Tags: security

What is a difference between security token and security ticket?

I have seen these terms been used interchangeably. Are there "industry standard" definitions of these? or are these terms defined differently depending on technology/protocol/implementation?

Comment: The terms mean the same thing. They are indeed interchangeable, though I have heard token used more in security circles.

Comment: @Oded I probably shouldn't have even tried to answer this question, but I didn't read your profile until afterward. You know A LOT about tokens, and tickets, and security!

Comment: @FeralOink - My rep and comments shouldn't stop you from answering questions. I can tell you I don't know everything ;). And from your answer - it appears you are talking about a very specific context - SOAP, which may or may not be what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Feral - Don't assume that high reputation means much. It is an easy trap to fall into. Jon Skeet has said that a high reputation on Stack Overflow is mostly indicative of the time spent on the site ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words *token* and *ticket* depend greatly on the type of system you're dealing with; and in what context you are talking. On Windows NT derivatives, the concept of a **token** is an identity. When a user or service logs in to a system, the system validates their identity once, and mints a token, which is handed to that user/service and serves as their identity. The system then doesn't need to validate identity every time a program opens a file, for example. This basically ensures a clean separation between authentication (proving a user/service is who they say they are) and authorization (determining whether a user/service can access some resource).

On the other hand, (again for NT derivatives) the word **ticket** usually refers to [Kerberos tickets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)). These are used for two machines on a domain to be able to prove each others' identity. After proving one's identity to the domain controller (with traditional means such as password or smart card), the domain controller mints a ticket which can be passed to remote machines to verify identity.

If one is dealing with a remote machine, then it is likely both tickets and tokens are involved. For instance, if machine A opens a file share on machine B, then machine A validates the user using it with the domain controller, thus getting a Kerberos ticket. It then uses the Kerberos ticket to verify its identity with machine B. Machine B then creates a session for machine A, minting a token, to serve as that session identity for local authorization queries on machine B.

As Feral and Oded have elsewhere in this question though, this is very domain-specific language.

Answer (score 3):

A **security token** becomes a **security ticket** after a request for service is successfully authenticated. For SOAP, after receiving a SOAP message as confirmation, that security ticket is used for all subsequent requests. I think of a security token as higher level, more strict, whereas a security ticket is issued by a service provider and more narrowly useful.

According to this (no longer current) MSDN article, **[Brokered Authentication: Security Token Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650503.aspx#wss_ch1_brokauthsts_topic6)**:

> ...the client obtains a Security Context Token (SCT) (which demonstrates
>   that the client has been authenticated) from the STS and caches it.
>   After the client is authenticated with the STS, the client can use the
>   session token to request a service token for communication with a
>   service. The way the STS validates a **security token** presented by a
>   client and issues **service tokens** is similar to how the Kerberos
>   protocol validates a ticket-granting ticket and issues a service
>   ticket.

"Security token" has the same meaning as I am familiar with, but "service token" is used instead of "service ticket". The last part of the sentence, about Kerberos, reads really oddly i.e. a  "ticket-granting ticket".

Here's another explanation, where the terminology is more familiar to me (it is specifically about **[SAML for Single Sign On](https://www.realtown.com/mattcohen/blog/singlesignonthroughrets)**):

> SSO in its basic form just means that a service provider will trust
>   authentication credentials provided using the SAML standard by an
>   identity provider... Please note that when we use the term ‘token’,
>   we’re not talking about some sort of physical security token, but
>   something else entirely, a security ticket that is part of the SAML
>   standard.

Now for the next part of your question, which was about standards. **[This blog post](http://coheigea.blogspot.com/2011/12/ws-securitypolicy-examples-in-apache.html)** has four OASIS WS use cases for security tokens (policy?), with links to the standards. In case you have any problem accessing that, OASIS has a page of **[standards for security tokens](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/security-policy/examples/ws-sp-usecases-examples-cs-02.html)**.